# Xcode: how to set delegates for subviews created using Storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

here is my problem.

I have a viewcontroller in which I create 2 views using UIView(top view and bottom view) and each view has a button.
I generate the Top view programatically along with the button, and set the delegate. The top view works -- when the click the button, I see the NSLog "button clicked" in the delegate in viewcontroller.

I've created teh bottom view using Storyboard so that I can see the view and the button placement visually. This doesnt work. I dont see the button click log either in the the button click method associated with the view before it hands over to the delegate defined in the view controller.

How do I set delegates for buttons and other objects created in subviews using Storyboard?

Comment: How many view controller classes do you have?

Comment: I have multiple view controllers, all controlled by a tabview controller. So, for this exercise, it is just a single view controller

Answer (score 1):

Left click on the (visual) UIButton in the storyboard file. You will see a small menu that pops up. The menu will show a list of properties (including the delegate property) for that object. Then simply right click on the delegate property, hold it, and drag it (a blue line will appear) and link it to the object's delegate.

This link might also help: 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Comment: delegate property doesnt show up when ctrl-click the UIButton. There are other properties: triggered seques, outlet collections, send events, referencing outlets, referencing outlet collections

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to post a pic to show my view controller, but it is pretty simple -- a view controller with a UIView that occupies lower half of the view controller. The UIView has a button, which I need to respond to in the viewcontroller (which is the superview)

Comment: Update:  I can associate the button from subview to a method in its superview (ie. click the button in subview, you will get a method activated in the view controller). But, I want some processing to be done in the subview itself before delegating to superview.... this is where I have a problem